# built SIP client in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, sip, opensips

Is it possible to build a SIP client using JAVASCRIPT for a server not supporting WEBSOCKET or WEBRTC?

Comment: Please note that SIP is just signaling mechanism and you still need to rely on WebRTC for the media streams (including all the mandatory requirements such as ICE and DTLS-SRTP support on the server side). To deviate from the embedded WebRTC path you'll have to write an extension for the browsers you are targeting or write a full fledged desktop app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a UDP or TCP socket to send your SIP messages towards the SIP server. Since Javascript supports UDP sockets([link](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html)), it should be possible. Anyhow since it is not that easy to implement a SIP useragent/transaction-layer, so I would google for Javascript SIP stacks, that supports TCP/UDP.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Paulius Nyoumi : If the above answers the question, please mark the question as solved. Thx

Comment: @Paulius Nyoumi, is the answer enough for you? If so, please mark the answer as correct.